# How to use Scope inside other Scope?

Tags: sequelize.js

How in description the **scope** for one model I can use **scope** from other model?

I have first scope:

```
includeBookingSessionAndUsers: (userId) => ({
    include: [
        {
            model: sequelize.model('BookingSession'),
            where: {
                [Op.or]: [
                    { studentId: userId },
                    { tutorId: userId },
                ],
            }
        },
    ],
}),
```

I need use inside of first scope next scope:

```
includeStudentAndTutor: () => ({
    include: [
        {
            model: sequelize.model('User'),
            as: 'tutor',
        },
        {
            model: sequelize.model('User'),
            as: 'student',
        }
    ]
}),
```

So that in the end it would be the same as if I just had one scope with a nested include:

```
includeBookingSessionAndUsers: (userId) => ({
    include: [
        {
            model: sequelize.model('BookingSession'),
            where: {
                [Op.or]: [
                    { studentId: userId },
                    { tutorId: userId },
                ],
            },
            include: [
                {
                    model: sequelize.model('User'),
                    as: 'tutor',
                },
                {
                    model: sequelize.model('User'),
                    as: 'student',
                }
            ]
        },
    ],
})
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found a solution.

This scope remains unchanged.

```
includeStudentAndTutor: () => ({
    include: [
        {
            model: sequelize.model('User'),
            as: 'tutor',
        },
        {
            model: sequelize.model('User'),
            as: 'student',
        }
    ]
}),
```

Please note that it is described for the `BookingSession` model

Our second scope, within which `includeStudentAndTutor` will be called, is described in the `Conversations` model and here is its working description

```
            includeBookingSessionAndUsers: (userId) => ({
                include: [
                    {
                        model: sequelize.model('BookingSession'),
                        where: {
                            [Op.or]: [
                                { studentId: userId },
                                { tutorId: userId },
                            ],
                        },
                    },
                    sequelize.model('BookingSession').scope('includeStudentAndTutor'),
                ],
            }),
```

which returns the same result as if this scope did not use the `includeStudentAndTutor` scope, but was simply described like this:

```
includeBookingSessionAndUsers: (userId) => ({
    include: [
        {
            model: sequelize.model('BookingSession'),
            where: {
                [Op.or]: [
                    { studentId: userId },
                    { tutorId: userId },
                ],
            },
            include: [
                {
                    model: sequelize.model('User'),
                    as: 'tutor',
                },
                {
                    model: sequelize.model('User'),
                    as: 'student',
                }
            ]
        },
    ],
})
```